# How is a motorcycle whip possible?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, energy-conservation

For clarification on what I'm talking about, please see this video link at 0:40 https://youtu.be/YAUOFy1QyiE?t=40

The riders appear to be breaking the laws of physics by rotating one way, and then changing their direction of rotation mid flight.

I've tried to research this, but all I can find is extremely vague and unscientific explanations.

Can anyone help me understand this, or point me to a source where I can learn about it?

Comment: It's probably the angular momentum of the front wheel. When changing the axis of rotation you get a force that's perpendicular to this.  See for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5cRb0xvPJ2M.

Answer (score 0):

To me, this looks like it can be explained by the classic experiment of standing on a round table and holding a spinning bicycle wheel.

If you stand on a turntable, take a bicycle wheel, hold it horizontally, and give it an angular velocity along the $+z$ axis, the flip it upside down so that $\omega$ points in the $-z$ direction, you will start spinning about the $+z$ axis yourself

This is because of the conservation of angular momentum. $L_{z_0} = x$ where $x$ is positive. When you flip the wheel, the $L_{z_{wheel}}=-L_{z_0}$. So to conserve the original $L_{z_0}$, you will need to be spinning in the opposite direction.

In the video, you can see that the rider is tilting the motorcycle so that they are kind of "holding the wheels [of their motorcycle] horizontally" from the previous example. Then, to start turning the other direction, they lean other way and flip the wheels. To conserve angular momentum, the rider's angular momentum will need to increase in the opposite direction that the wheel is spinning.

Try using the right hand rule to find the direction of the angular momentum of the riders and the wheels before and after the wheel flip, you will find that they will be alternating so as to conserve the initial $L$